# Get top 1 row of each Id by Where in

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance, where-in

I have a table which I want to get the latest entry for each parameters in where in

```
select GpsData.VehicleId, GpsData.Id, GpsData.DateTime
from GpsData
where GpsData.VehicleId in (44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058)
order by GpsData.VehicleId desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    VehicleId, 
    Id, 
    [DateTime]
FROM GpsData
WHERE VehicleId in (44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)
```

We can use dynamic query for that as below:

```
 DECLARE @Ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = '44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058', @sql NVARCHAR(3000)

 SET @sql = '
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES VehicleId, 
        Id, 
        [DateTime] 
    FROM GpsData 
    WHERE VehicleId IN (' + @ids + ') 
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Susang, I really like this slick approach, but I had to find, that it is very slow... The sorting will be performed twice (once for `ROW_NUMBER` and again for the `ORDER BY`. Quite a draw back with larger sets... It is much better to use a CTE and and `ROW_NUMBER` as a column and use `WHERE RNr=1` at the end...

Comment: thanks a lot  . how i can use parameter for this approach                         declare @Ids nvarchar(Max) =44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058                                                                                    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    VehicleId, 
    Id, 
    [DateTime]
FROM GpsData
WHERE VehicleId in (@ids)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)

Comment: We can use dynamic query as updated above please check.

Answer (score 2):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select g.VehicleId, g.Id, g.DateTime
from GpsData g
where g.VehicleId in (44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058)
and not exists (
  select 1 from GpsData
  where VehicleId = g.VehicleId and DateTime > g.DateTime 
)
order by g.VehicleId desc;
```

or with [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
select t.VehicleId, t.Id, t.DateTime
from (
  select VehicleId, Id, DateTime,
    row_number() over (partition by VehicleId order by DateTime desc) as rn   
  from GpsData 
  where VehicleId in (44, 1054, 1055, 31, 22, 1058)
) as t
where t.rn = 1
order by t.VehicleId desc;
```

Comment: I'd prefer the second appraoch... And I would shift the `FROM(...)` into a CTE, but this just syntactic sugar. +1 from my side.